# Pegar valores referente a div clicada com javascript

Tags: javascript

Como faço para pegar os valores correspondente a `DIV` clicada?`

Exemplo da primeira div se for clicada, retorna:

> aID = 1
>
> aCodigo = 8477459164
>
> aNome = Sala

```js
function vistoriaIniciar(object) {
  let aID     = object.document.getElementsByClassName('aID').value;
  let aCodigo = object.document.getElementsByClassName('aCodigo').value;
  let aNome   = object.document.getElementsByClassName('aNome').value;
 
  
  alert(aID +" - "+ aCodigo +" - "+ aNome);
}
```

```html
<div id="divListaAmbientes" class="">


  <div class="lista fade" onclick="vistoriaIniciar(this)">
    <h1>Sala</h1>
    <input class="aID" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input class="aCodigo" type="hidden" value="8477459164">
    <input class="aNome" type="hidden" value="Sala">
  </div>
  

  <div class="lista fade" onclick="vistoriaIniciar(this)">
    <h1>Quarto</h1>
    <input class="aID" type="hidden" value="2">
    <input class="aCodigo" type="hidden" value="8477459164">
    <input class="aNome" type="hidden" value="Quarto">
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você define um atributo `onclick` em algum elemento HTML e chama uma função passando o `this` como argumento, você receberá a instância do elemento.

Então, como essa instância que você recebe como parâmetro implementa a interface [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element), você pode invocar métodos como `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelector`, entre outros.

Desse modo, o problema está aqui:

```js
object.document.getElementsByClassName('aID').value;
```

O elemento que você está recebendo não possui uma propriedade `document`. O `document` ao qual você se refere é uma global nos browsers, e não pode ser acessado através de outro elemento.

Basta fazer desse modo:

```js
object.getElementsByClassName('aID')[0].value;
//                                  ↑↑↑
//           Note que utilizamos o `[0]` aqui.
```

Note também que eu adicionei um `[0]` ao final da chamada [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName), já que esse [método retorna um `HTMLCollecion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName#Return_value), que não possui o método `value`. Para tal, precisamos obter o primeiro elemento retornado (ou algum outro à sua escolha).

Comment: Você foi mais rápido do que eu e pior que para essa pergunta não tem nem como dar outra resposta.

Comment: Luiz, muito obrigado pela sua explicação!